# Discoloration on load center bus bar

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, safety

I recently replaced our main load center with a larger one. I was planning to use the old, smaller panel as a sub panel in an addition we are building.

After removing the breakers from the old panel, I noticed some discoloration on the bus bar, where the breakers attach. The panel and all breakers were Square D QO brand. The contacts on the breakers don't seem to have this.

[image: bus bars]
[image: breaker contacts]
[image: panel label]

Is this panel still safe to use? What causes this? Should I use some electrical contact cleaner on the bar?

Comment: Are you sure that the  brownish color is not due to some contact grease? It may have come originally from the breaker(s). Try to see if it will wash off with a Q-tip and some isopropyl alcohol.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the labeling on the old panel?

Comment: Were the old breakers all Square D breakers, or Siemens type QD breakers?

Comment: @MichaelKaras I will try that tomorrow in the daylight.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Added photo, I will have to get to my shop to get a better one or if you're looking for a different label, this is what I had on my phone.

Comment: @Harper They are all Square D QO breakers.

Comment: @MichaelKaras please add your comment as an answer, you got it right, it seems to be grease, I'm able to scrape it off and the metal underneath is clean.

Comment: OK. Answer posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that the brownish color is not due to some contact grease? It may have come originally from the breaker(s). Try to see if it will wash off with a Q-tip and some isopropyl alcohol.

Be careful to not scrape the bus bar with any sharp metal tool because the silver colored plating on them is quite thin and you risk exposing the underlying copper.